# Data gateway timout error during scheduled refresh

Tags: powerbi

I have an entity connected to a SQL Server database.

The gateway is installed on the server with the lastest version and all seems ok.

When I refresh the data manually in Power BI service, it takes about 1h30 minutes and the data is refreshed without errors.

However, when the data is refreshed by schedule (once a day at 1:00AM), it throws a time out error.

Why is this and how can I fix this problem?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Is there a SQL Server backup/maintenance schedule that runs at that time? How much data is it (row size)?

Comment: Hi @Jonee thanks, no, there's no other schedule at that time. The table has 320K rows.

Comment: 90 minutes is very long time for a refresh. Did you considered using DirectQuery for this report?

Comment: You might be hitting to 2 hour time limit, for 320K rows that seems a long time. I would recommend that the SQL Query or something on the database side be looked at